# How to get a certain string in a text file

Tags: string, text, vbscript, pseudocode

Here's an example text file named "sample.txt":

```
This is a sample text file and I need to return this string > "myScript.sql".
And this another string: "myNewScript.sql"
How do I do it using VBScript?
```

And what I want to do is to return the "myScript.sql" and "myNewScript.sql" string using VB Script.

Like:

```
If string's file extension =  ".sql"
  THEN
    myString = Scan left and get the string until the QUOTE (") symbol.
    Echo myString
```

Something like that.

Comment: Why have you tagged your question with javascript if it's really about VBScript?

Comment: Why you tagged your question with javascript and ask for VB in your question?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Changed it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use regular expressions in this case:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set file = objFSO.OpenTextFile("sample.txt" , ForReading)  
Const ForReading = 1

Dim re
Set re = new regexp 
re.Pattern = """(\w+?[.]sql)"""
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global = True

Dim line
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    line = file.ReadLine
    For Each m In re.Execute(line)
       Wscript.Echo m.Submatches(0)
    Next
Loop
```

By executing it with:

```
cscript //nologo test.vbs
```

With the file sample.txt:

```
This is a sample text file and I need to return this string > "myScript.sql".
And this another string: "myNewScript.sql"
How do I do it using VBScript?
```

You'll get this:

```
myScript.sql
myNewScript.sql
```

Comment: I would change the expression to `""(\w+?\.sql)""` to make it a more specific. Also, the code in its current form handles only a single match per line. Setting the `Global` property to `True` and evaluating the lines in a loop (`For Each m In re.Execute(line) : WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0) : Next`) fixes that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You're right. You can edit my answer if you want to :)

Comment: Thanks for adding that! I noticed that it only handles single match per line! Thank you so much everyone.

Comment: I modified this `"""(\w+?[.]sql)"""`  into this `"(\w+?[.]sql)"` to echo it no matter what characters encloses the string I need to get.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers How can I put other file extensions? For example I also want to search for .pkg, .pks, etc? How can I add that to the re.pattern?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. `"(\w+?[.]sql|\w+?[.]pkg|\w+?[.]pks)"`

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1

Dim fso
    Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim fileMatch
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = """([^""]*\.sql)"""
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        For Each fileMatch in .Execute(fso.OpenTextFile("sample.txt", ForReading).ReadAll())
            WScript.Echo fileMatch.SubMatches(0)
        Next 
    End With
```

This will search the file contents for quoted strings that end in `.sql`, extracting the text inside the quotes